# Modifying a JSON with values from another JSON

Tags: json

I'm trying to migrate a report to [Google's](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/php_example.html) chart api.
I'm having a beginner JS issue with JSON's that I haven't been able to find a solution for.

I'm using a server side scripting page that will pass the results of a retrieve object request. The results are in JSON format similar to this.

```
[{"SendID":1185402,"EmailName":"SomeName0","EmailCount":0}]
```

Google's data example wants this information to look like this in the Row:

```
{"rows": [{"c":[{"v":"someString0"},{"v":"someString1"},{"v":0}]}]}
```

I've solved the "col" format, but manipulating the "retrieve" data to fit the "row" format has me stumped.
So ideally I would like to insert the value of SendID into someString0, value of EmailName into someString1, and the value of EmailCount into 0

Thanks for any advice, I hope this provided enough detail.

Comment: What is the server-side script? PHP? Are you looking to manipulate the JSON output from the server, or to manipulate the JSON in JS/client code before it's sent to Google? I would think it would be easier to manipulate the server output to achieve the correct JSON structure/object.